# What improved frequency response means?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, frequency-response

I was looking at the question "what feedback exactly means"(applied in Op-amps). In the negative feedback even though there is a decrease in the op-amps overall gain, it's widely used because it improves the frequency response of the operational amplifier. So what does this mean exactly?

Comment: I don't think those are duplicates. This question is about how negative feedback influences the frequency response, not how negative feedback works in general.

Comment: Please provide a link to the question you looked at.

Comment: "...even though there is a decrease in the op-amps overall gain...it improves the frequency response..."  I believe the answer you're looking for has to do with gain and phase.  For stability, the gain of an op-amp must fall below 0dB when the phase reaches -180 degrees, thus deliberately lowering the gain with feedback can ensure a stable response.

Comment: I am just trying to understand what "improved frequency response" means, in simple words!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative feedback decreases the gain at low frequencies but does not affect it much at high frequencies. The frequency range over which the gain is almost constant is increased. Compare the -3dB points of the two amplifier circuits below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGoPFd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]